# Remove trailing slash and index.html in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, mod-rewrite

I seem to be stuck here trying to figure out how to redirect the following scenarios:

```
/foo/index.html    -> /foo (remove trailing slash, index.html as 301)
/foo/              -> /foo (remove trailing slash as 301)
/foo               -> No redirect, shows the file at /foo/index.html
/foo/notindex.html -> No redirect, shows the file at /foo/notindex.html
```

I believe the relevant lines in my .htaccess are

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /foo/ to /foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L,E=LOOP:1]

# Redirect /foo to /foo/index.html
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\?.*)?$ $1/index.html$2 [L]

# Redirect /foo/index.html to /foo
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

but of course, the contents of the entire [.htaccess](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=za56zYCP) file could come in handy here too. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 11/13/14**

I trashed all those rules above and am starting over:

```
# Remove trailing slash
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/index.html [L]
```

This satisfies 2 of the 4 points. To be more specific:

```
1 https://server.com/foo            renders the /foo/index.html correctly without redirect
2 https://server.com/foo/           renders the /foo/index.html correctly but should redirect to /foo instead of rendering
3 https://server.com/foo/index.html renders the /foo/index.html correctly but should redirect to /foo instead of rendering
4 https://server.com/foo/foo.html   renders the /foo/foo.html correctly
```

So now that #1 and #4 are correct, how can I add 301 redirects for #2 and #3 without breaking it or looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly the answer to your question but you should think twice about removing trailing slashes for directories.

The doc about [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) warns from potential problems (a mess with relative urls and others). And you can save some headaches by only redirecting with a 301 `/dir/index.html` to `/dir/` (nearly your point 3), and using `DirectoryIndex index.html` directive.

Comment: This is the route I have chosen. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Aren't your last two entries cancelling each other out? `# Redirect /foo to /foo/index.html`  then the other way `# Redirect /foo/index.html to /foo`

If it just for those individual files?  Then I'd try:

```
# 301 Redirect /foo/index.html to /foo
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^foo/index\.html$ /foo? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# 301 Redirect /foo/ to /foo
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^foo/$ /foo? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

If your trying to do it for multiple files in one swoop, then try:

```
# 301 Redirect remove trailing index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.html HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# 301 Redirect remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also specify specific directories that you don't want too apply this rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !I-want-a-trailing-slash-on-this-one/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. It gives an Internal Service Error when rendering the page. Though I think you are right about the 2nd rewrite rule in my existing htaccess...